# In C++, does initializing a string but not assigning it to anything result in memory usage?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to understand how `const char * foo = "hello";` works under the hood. I interpret it as a string is created, and then a pointer points to it in memory.

So, does this line of code:

`"hello";`

take any memory?

Comment: The question text is the opposite of the title

Answer (score 1):

`"hello";`

This does not take any memory because any modern compiler would optimize this away since it literally does *nothing*. If it was something more like:

`const char* foo = "hello";`

As you stated in your question, `foo` would be a `char*` to a static string that is baked into the program executable. Therefore the only run-time memory is the pointer to that string location.

Comment: When an executable is loaded, the static data may be mapped or loaded into memory, e.g. the pointer doesn't actually point at the hard disk.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question.

a string literal must take space in the static storage (the "data segment"), so yes, that string literal does take a place somewhere in the process memory.

but a good optimize will recognize that this literal is not reference nowhere, and will probably remove that string away. so I highly doubt that a program compiled with optimization on will retain that string.

Comment: It could be in the "code segment" (or anywhere really)

Answer (score 1):

If you simply execute `"hello";` as an expression, almost any compiler will (probably even with optimization disabled) optimize it away to nothing.

That doesn't necessarily relate well to your starting point though. Given:

```
const char * foo = "hello";
```

You have another issue to consider: is that at namespace scope (i.e., outside any function)? If it's at global scope, the compiler probably *can't* optimize it away, even if it's not used. The problem is pretty simple: if it's outside any function, then some *other* source file could contain something like `extern char const *foo;`, and by doing so get access to `foo`, even though it's not used in the current file. Since the compiler only looks at one source file at a time, it has no way of detecting such a situation.

Depending on how smart it is, the linker (which *does* look at all the object files at once) may be able to detect that `foo` is never used, and based on that it could optimize it away.

If this definition is inside a function, then the compiler can detect whether it's used based solely on the content of that function, so we're back to a situation where it can be optimized away much more dependably.

Answer (score -2):

I suggest looking into this link: http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/79-the-stack-and-the-heap/

foo points to a location on the stack in your case. So, yes, it takes up memory.

Edit: Sorry misread your code. You aren't assigning "hello" to anything.
So in your case, no.

Comment: `foo` may live on a stack in typical implementations, but in those same implementations it almost certainly won't point anywhere in the stack.